# doGet Macro Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I installed this (http://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fentaq%2FGoogleAppsScript%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2FScriptDbVisualizer&session_token=bydEWEJYqmFTjUAF1GnS7tK7yBl8MTM2MjI4Njk1M0AxMzYyMjcyNTUz) scriptDBConsole in order to check if my data is being stored correctly in ScriptDB.

When I ran the web app, an error occured that said: **Unknown macro doGet**

I thought that maybe some of my original coding was what was messing it up, so I tried to run the web app as a new project with just the original coding, but there was still an error.

Not sure what the error is... All authorizations are correct.

If anyone could offer insight on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

~Noelle

Comment: From the script editor, try [selecting doGet from the dropdown menu and running it there](http://i.imgur.com/2kvn0g7.png).  It seems that doGet isn't being defined properly. I copied all of the code from the github, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Phil Bozak:

From the script editor, try selecting doGet from the dropdown menu and running it there. It seems that doGet isn't being defined properly. I copied all of the code from the github, and it worked for me.